# How To Follow Using Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'll be using BlackBerry Token For This Action.

What's The API code for following users is it /follow or /subscribers

And can anyone give its html codes.

Answer (score 0):

Since Graph API v2.0, it's no longer possible to do this via the API.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api

> `/me/subscribers` and `/me/subscribedto` have been removed.